# Multi task overriding variables

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, multitasking, overriding

Firstly sorry for my bad english!

Then now, my problem: I have a process that I need to run fast - it a large amout of data and I want to run in a multithread/multitask way - (I don't know if it's the best way to do this)

I have two subs(), as following:

```
 Sub read_file_do_something_and_insert_table()
        Dim t As Task
        Dim FULLPATH As String = ""
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim arr() As String
        Try
            Using oReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FULLPATH)
                While Not oReader.EndOfStream
                    Try
                        i = i + 1
                        arr = oReader.ReadLine.Split(vbTab)

                        t = New Task(Sub() multiTask({arr(0)}))
                        t.Start()

                        Me.Text = i
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                End While
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        t.Wait()
        MsgBox("Successfully completed.")
        Me.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Sub multiTask(ByVal Params() As Object)
        Using oConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Using oCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
                oConn.Open()
                oCmd.Connection = oConn
                oCmd.Parameters.Clear()
                oCmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[PROC_THAT_DO_SOME_TREATMENTS_AND_INSERT_IN_A_TABLE]"
                oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Params(0))
                oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

I was able to run the code above in multithread - and it's run perfectly (18000rec/s), however, the control of thread termination gets a bit tricky, so I thought about changing the code to run in multitask using the task.wait () command.

But when I run this code, the values ​​of the variables are being overridden. This way, I always have the last line of the file being read as a result. This does not happen if I use the Thread class - but when I use the Task class, yes.
Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you'd be better of calling `Parallel.ForEach`. That will handle the parallelism for you automatically and will inherently wait until all items have been processed.  I'd suggest something like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim filePath As String 'Store file path here.
    Dim lines = File.ReadLines(filePath)

    'This will process the lines of the file in parallel.
    Parallel.ForEach(lines, AddressOf ProcessLine)

    'When you get here, all lines in the file have been processed.
End Sub

'Process one line of text.
Private Sub ProcessLine(line As String)
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try the way you put it - I did not know this way to do it. Thank you! I post feedback here as soon as I implement it.